# How to throw facebook token to own server securely?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm developing iOS app(Swift) using 3rd party(facebook) authentication. I encountered a question which is how I can throw the access token from facebook to my own server.

I've been writing something like below..

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://example.com/user/fb", access_token: facebook_access_token)
```

but I'm not sure this is safe enough.
Not only that, when I implement email/password login as well, I've been writing something like below..

```
var user = [email: "ex@mple.com", pass: "password"]
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://example.com/user/", user: user)
```

Are those safe enough? Or if there're best practices please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending your credentials via SSL prevents others from reading the values in the middle. So, it's theoretically secure. ie: It goes through the security provided by the transport layer.

However, it's not the recommended approach to send plaintext passwords to the server. The correct way is to hash the password at each client, then send the hash value to the server. At the server, you should compare whether the hashes match. You might need to do some changes to your server logic. But, in the long run, it should be worth.

Comment: _“The correct way is to hash the password at each client, then send the hash value to the server”_ – that alone won’t change much. In scenario A I can get access, if I can sniff the password that you send to the server somewhere along the way. And in scenario B I get access, if I can sniff that hash … This only makes sense if you implement some form of challenge-response on top of it.

Comment: Hi CBroe, Hashed values are really really difficult to decrypt. So, that's why I proposed to hash the password at the client which in this case is the iPhone. Therefore, anyone in the middle would only get the hash value rather than getting the complete password. That seems slightly better than exposing the password, don't you think?

Comment: If your server grants the client access based on that it sends a simple hash of the password – then I don’t need to “decrypt” that hash, I just need to send that same hash value (which I am able to sniff, in this scenario). Simple client-side hashing would make some sense if SSL/TLS was not available – in that case it would at least prevent that the password gets send as “plain text.”

Comment: I see your point now. Thanks for explaining. So why do you recommend a Challenge response mechanism? How does that prevent such security breaches? Would you mind explaining it in brief. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One way of doing it would be to have the server send a one-time token to the client first, and the client then uses that token as “salt” in the password hashing. It sends the hash and the token back to the server, and the server then calculates the hash of password and token itself. After the client has responded, the server then marks the token as invalid/expired – so even if I now send the same hash and token that I have sniffed, the server would refuse my request.

Comment: (Drawback of this simple approach, it would require the password to be stored in plain on the server. But there’s ways around that as well – but going into details of that, would get rather too broad here. Additional measures, such as also recording the timestamp of when the token was issued, and then refusing access if the answer comes in after more than timespan X has passed, can also be thrown in.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe for your in detail explanation. Yes, I would agree this is more secure and more difficult to exploit!

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruchira and CBroe. I will implement the function as you guys instructed!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking whether its safe to send it over the network. If you are using SSL encrypted URL and pinning the SSL to your app then yes it is. Here is blog post explaining how to do SSL pinning on IOS

https://possiblemobile.com/2013/03/ssl-pinning-for-increased-app-security/